# How to show fullscreen preview in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, fullscreen

I sometimes need to preview the image I edit in GIMP full screen. I could do this by exporting current image and opening it in a viewer like Geeqie, but that's quite inconvenient. Is there a better way to get a fullscreen preview without leaving GIMP?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks to [this post](https://l00pback.wordpress.com/2009/09/05/gimp-fullscreen-previews/) I have a workaround for the lack (or hiddenness) of preview feature in GIMP. Full screen mode can be used for this. You can set it up so that it has different set of GUI options from windowed mode. Configure it as follows.

1. Go to *Edit*→*Preferences*→*Image Windows*→*Appearance*.
2. Uncheck all the checkboxes in the *Default Appearance in Fullscreen Mode* section.
3. Set background mode & color to your preference for preview.
4. Press *OK* and restart GIMP to actually apply the defaults.

Now, after you press <kbd>F11</kbd> followed by <kbd>Tab</kbd>, you'll be in preview mode without toolbars (which are toggled by <kbd>Tab</kbd>). To fit the image to screen, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

Comment: restarting gimp after applying the changes in settings was enough